# Different hash results in Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, hash, sha256

I have simple code on Java backend side that is hashing some bytes.

```
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA256;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ShaTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var input = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        var result = new SHA256.Digest().digest(input);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

The result equals to  `[-118, -123, 31, -8, 46, -25, 4, -118, -48, -98, -61, -124, 127, 29, -33, 68, -108, 65, 4, -46, -53, -47, 126, -12, -29, -37, 34, -58, 120, 90, 13, 69]`

Now on frontend side, I need to hash the same bytes and I expect to have the same result using `js-sha256` library. Hash function is as simple as

```
  hash(input: any): any {
    return sha.sha256.update(input).digest();
  }
```

And I'm trying to hash it using several different inputs

```
    const rawInput = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    console.log('rawInput', this.hash(rawInput));

    console.log('uint8Input', this.hash(new Uint8Array(rawInput)));
    
    console.log('int8Input', this.hash(new Int8Array(rawInput)));
    
    const intArr = new Int8Array(new ArrayBuffer(8));
    intArr.set(rawInput);
    console.log('intArrayWithBuffer', this.hash(intArr));

    const uintArr = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(8));
    uintArr.set(rawInput);
    console.log('uintArrayWithBuffer', this.hash(uintArr));
```

However, the result is different than on backend side. Frontend instead produces
`[138, 133, 31, 248, 46, 231, 4, 138, 208, 158, 195, 132, 127, 29, 223, 68, 148, 65, 4, 210, 203, 209, 126, 244, 227, 219, 34, 198, 120, 90, 13, 69]`

Why is that happening?

Comment: 256 - 118 = 138

Comment: The Java values are signed 8 bit numbers, the Javascript values are effectively unsigned.

Comment: You should study the topic [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).